# PHP output buffer settings ignored by server

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I have been trying to flush the output of certain scripts to the browser on demand, but they do not work on our production server.

For instance, I tried running the "Phoca Changing Collation tool" (find it on Google) and I don't see any output until the script finishes executing.

I've tried immediately flushing the buffer on other scripts that work fine on any server but this one using the following code:

```
echo "something";
ob_flush();
flush();
```

Setting "ob_implicit_flush(1);" doesn't help either.

The server is Apache 2.2.21 with PHP 5.2.17 running on Linux. You can see our php.ini file here if that will help:
http://www.smallfiles.org/download/1123/php.ini.html

This isn't the only problem we are having with the server ignoring in-script directives.  The server also ignores timeout coding such as:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 900*60);
```

AND

```
set_time_limit(86400);
```

Script always times out at the php.ini default.

Doesn't seem to matter if script is executed in IE or Firefox.

Tried "ini_set('zlib.output_compression_level', 'Off');" and checked that it is "Off" in the php.ini file. The code "apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);" causes a fatal error so tried uploading a .htaccess file with the "mod_gzip_on No" directive. Neither helps.

Tried running Apache as fcgi and suphp, but same results.

Server is NOT in safe mode.

Pullin ma hair out!

Comment: I've solved half of this. By adding "SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary" to a .htaccess file in the script's directory, I can get it to flush the buffer correctly. However, I still can't get the scripts to run long enough without timing out on the php.ini default. Max execution time is still ignored. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the output buffer problem, I needed to turn off gzip compression inside the .htaccess file.

To fix the timeout issue, I checked my Apache log files and found it wasn't PHP but in the Apache configuration:
The timeout specified has expired: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed

Had to increase the Apache timeout to prevent this problem. This apparently arises from Apache waiting for more content to hit the buffer before the timeout resets.